# how to use button attribute value inside a modal vue.js3 component

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, bootstrap-modal

I'm new in vue.js and laravel.
I have a "test.blade.php" file witch contains many buttons with different "id"s. I'm using bootstrap modal style.
when I click the each button, the modal form witch is located in .vue component comes up.
I want to use the "id" attribute of clicked button to read details data from my database by axios.

**test.blade.php:**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop" data-bs-whatever="1" id="1">details of id 1</button>

<div id="app">
    <modal-component></modal-component>
</div>

@endsection
```

**ModalComponent.vue:**

```
<template>
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop">
        modal
    </button>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="staticBackdropLabel">Modal title</h1>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                     <ul>
                         <li>
                             {{details.id}}
                         </li>
                         <li>
                             {{details.name}}
                         </li>
                         <li>
                             {{details.type}}
                         </li>
                     </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            details: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
    },
    created(){
        let url0='/api/Materials/' + ?????
        axios.get(url0)
            .then(response=>this.details=response.data);
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted successfully')
    }
}
</script>
```

what should I do?

Comment: Looks like you only have one button with an id attribute and that button isn't inside the Vue app... and then you have almost the same button but without id and inside the vue app?

I would advise you to move the button that needs to be clicked inside the vue app and then check out vue documentations for handling events https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#listening-to-events

Especially @click which seems to be what you need